# Execute PHP file using AJAX without any data input

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

What is the ajax syntax to execute a php file that doesn't need any data input? Is there an issue with my Jquery or should I focus on the PHP? I get the expected alerts from jquery below.

The DB connection code for my PHP has been checked. As you can see from further below, I just need the PHP to increment a table record. No data input is required.

Any suggestions please?

Jquery:

```
if (question==answer){
alert("Correct!");

$.ajax({  type: "POST",  
          url: "incrementScore.php" });

}else{
alert("Wrong!");
}
```

PHP:

```
$oldScoreQ="SELECT score FROM score WHERE scoreID='1'";
$oldScore = mysqli_query($dbc,$oldScoreQ);
$newScore = $oldScore++;
$update = "UPDATE score SET score =".$newScore."WHERE scoreID = 1";
mysqli_query($dbc,$update);
mysqli_close($dbc);
```

Comment: You should probably focus on your PHP file. What happens if you just go to the PHP page itself, without AJAX?

Comment: Did you name your table the same as the field? And why only update once if the value equals 1? `UPDATE score SET score = score + 1`

Comment: also for ajax you can use shorthand methods:http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/shorthand-methods/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**JS**

```
if (question==answer){
   alert("Correct!");
   $.ajax({type: "GET",url: "incrementScore.php"});

}else{
   alert("Wrong!");
}
```

**PHP**

```
$update = "UPDATE score SET score =score+1 WHERE scoreID = 1";
mysqli_query($dbc,$update);
mysqli_close($dbc);
```

Answer (score 2):

You miss a space in your Query which creates an error.

```
"UPDATE score SET score =".$newScore."WHERE scoreID = 1";
```

Should be

```
"UPDATE score SET score =".$newScore." WHERE scoreID = 1";
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, that is how you execute a php file, you simply call it with a regular GET -OR- POST request. I would use GET in this case though. You don't need to send any parameters to execute the file.

(check your php code though, that's the issue)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `incrementScore.php` is in the same folder as your current folder. You can check the current directory using the `getcwd` function. If everything is correct, then focus on your php file. Note that unless you do some measures anybody can send a request to that php file incrementing the given value.